Differential structure for spacetime manifold
In general relativity, a spacetime is modeled by a Lorentzian manifold, which of course is a differential manifold on its own, and the d.o.f.s of the gravity are realized by the lorentzian metric $g$.
But I read from wiki that a topological manifold can have distinct differential structures, especially for $\mathbb{R}^4$ one has infinitely many distinct differential structures (see Exotic R4). So I wonder whether there are some d.o.f.s on the differential structures of a given topological manifold, and how can we determine which differential structure to take to do the Einstein theory for a general spacetime manifold (such as the topological manifold $\mathbb{R}^4$)?

More on exotic differential structures.
